# Inverting a map from a finite 3D grid to 1D

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, computer-science

I need help with this mathematics question.

I have made a program on the computer that flattens a 3D array into a 1D array. A 3D array needs an x, y and z  but by using this formula (max x * max y * max z) + (max y * max z) + max z the array becomes 1D instead.

For example: 
an array of 30 x 30 x 30 can have 27930 possible locations (30 * 30 * 30 + 30 * 30 + 30)

If x=3 y=5 z=1 then (3 * 5 * 1) + (5 * 1) + 1 = 21

This speeds up processing time by removing nested loops. Seems to work fine.  The array is only meant to be used as a data storage so I will always know x y z as I iterate trough each coordinate.

However. I am wondering how do I go about it backwards?

Knowing 21 how do I find out x y z? Is a polynomial solving basic arithmetic however I have been unsuccessful in solving it. One idea was using x-y-z intercepts by plugging in zeros. Another was comparing first with smallest number by subtracting it (z) then with next biggest numbers (y * z) then with the biggest one (z * y * z).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It will not speed up iterations. You still iterate over $n_x \cdot n_y \cdot n_z$ elements.

Comment: It is not possible to recover the values; $f(3,5,1) = 21$ and $f(1,3,3)=21$, for example.

Comment: @FilipAnton where did you get that formula? It doesn't look like a simple flattening of multidimensional array.

Comment: I realize now my formula was incorrect.  ip6 further down has the correct answer.  @Kaster I found it online while looking for a way to speed up or remove nested loops.  The reason is faster has to do  with the way arrays are held in memory while a 1D array is a continuous block of data a multi dimensional array is a bunch of block of data at random places in memory requiring a lot of expensive memory manipulation. The drawback is a flat 1D array takes a bit more memory than a 3D one at the expense of faster access (totally worth it). Memory is cheaper than processing time.

Comment: @Kaster Also ,  a flattened multi dimensional array has more indexes adding extra overhead. For ex 3 x 3 x 3 should be 27 but if you flatten it (3 x 3 x 3) + (3 x 3) + 3 becomes 39.  This overhead becomes proportionally smaller for a bigger array. So you actually iterate over more items.  Correct me if I'm wrong still dodgy on the math but that should be right.

Comment: FilipAnton I don't think you got the idea of flattening right. Flattened array has the same elements as original array but all indices reduced to a single one. Otherwise, please explain where the overhead came from and what is stored in those extra elements. Also, if you think that @ip6 gave correct answer, then you should agree with that fact, since his answer also suggests that you eventually get $n_x \cdot n_y \cdot n_z $ elements.

Comment: Also, I don't buy that flattened array is that much faster than original array. I timed two python scripts, and results are almost identical.

Comment: @Kaster In my case the program is  in Java.  Check here for some benchmarks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512082/java-multi-dimensional-array-vs-one-dimensional 1D array are a tiny bit faster.
Regarding the size of the array I may be doing it wrong. x*y*z+y*z+z is in fact x*y*z so the size may in fact be smaller as a 3D array requires extra pointers that a 1D one does not.

Comment: @Kaster If you read trough the benchmark you will notice sometimes a 1D is faster than it's 3D counterpart. No 1 reason for the performance increase is on most machines  arithmetic operations are much faster than memory operations. In other words having to do the calculations to find x y z is faster than having to do computer memory RAM addresses calculations in a 3D array.

Comment: @trollworkout a tiny bit – maybe, not "lot of expensive memory manipulations". So it all boils down to the fact if that "tiny bit" is worthy to do back-and-forth index transformations. And for the size, you're confusing the memory that array needs in the memory as a structure with the number of elements associated with the array. Not sure about the first, but one thing I can tell you for sure - both original and flattened arrays have exactly the same number of elements. Period.

Comment: @KasterFor my application which is a 3D game with a lot of pieces to be rendered, I need to squeeze out as much processing power as I can. That extra speed boost is worth the trouble even if is 1%. As I am looping trough the array several times every frame anything that speeds up calculations helps me a lot. Now of course you wouldn't normally need a flat 3D array in most other cases as is confusing as hell. Proof of that is me coming here. In my case is something I really need.

Answer (score 3):

As written this is not going to work - you will have index collisions in your flattened matrix and will overwrite data.

For example $(1, 1, 7)$ would also map to the 1-D index $21$

Your formula should be (edited 15-feb-2018 for zero-based indexing):

$$ k = (x \times (\max(y)+1) \times (\max(z)+1)) + (y \times (\max(z)+1)) + z$$

And you invert it with

$$z=k\mod(\max(z)+1)$$

$$y=(k-z)/(\max(z)+1)\mod(\max(y)+1)$$

And so on --- this scheme can be extended to more than just 3D

EDIT: 
After user929304's comment below, I looked at this again (after 2 years) and realised I could have been clearer. I've also mixed up zero-based and one-based indexing, so here's another shot at it:

A worked example.

Assume $0\leq x\leq 5$, $0\leq y\leq 7$ and $0\leq z\leq 3$.

This means that $\max(z) = 3$ and $\max(y) = 7$.

Then $(2, 3, 1)$ should translate as follows:

$$ k = 2\times((7+1)\times(3+1)) + 3\times(3+1) + 1$$

$$ k = 64 + 12 + 1 = 77 $$

Starting with 77 and knowing $\max(z)+1 = 4$ and $\max(y)+1 = 8$ we can invert to get:

$$ z = 77 \mod 4 = 1 $$

and

$$ y = (77 - 1)/4 \mod 8 = 19 \mod 8 = 3 $$

and

$$ x = ((k - z)/(\max(z)+1) - y) / (\max(y)+1) = ((77-1)/4 - 3)/8 = (19-3)/8 = 2$$

The intuition is this - we are arranging all of the elements of the 3-D array in some systematic order so that we can count them.

Think of it like hours and minutes - the minutes add up until we get to sixty then they go back to zero and the hour counter increments. In the same way, we clock up $z$ until we get to its maximum value, then increment $y$ and set $z$ to zero again.

This means that every time we add one to the $y$ value we will have skipped ahead by $\max(z)+1$ in the linear array. And every time we add one to the $x$ value, we will have taken $y$ around the clock, which means we will have incremented $z$ by $(\max(y)+1)\times(\max(z)+1)$ and this is how far we will have jumped ahead in the linear array. The above formula encodes that.

Comment: Thank you ip6! You just pointed out the big mistake I made .  Doing some calculations is true that maps overlap with my old formula. Indeed this should be helpful as I was  going to use my badly done formula  in my program. Oh wow I can't even up your vote I need more reputation :(

Thank you so much!

Comment: No need to up vote me - just "accept" the answer. That's all the thanks I need.

Comment: @ip6 This is a great answer. Could you please intuitively [1] explain the main formula for $k$ above? E.g., why do we multiply $y$ by max of $z$ instead of max of $y?$ Similarly for the first term, why is $x$ multiplied by the term cross-term maximums?  [1]: Admittedly, there may not be an easy intuition here, I'm just trying to better visualise how the mapping is taking place. Thanks a bunch in advance.